# How to store large amount of geolocation data?

Tags: .net, mongodb, geolocation, postgis, spatial

I'm building an application that tracks user's journey through a country. Think of this: user enters a new country, turns on their location services and app begins to track their every move. Application will be able to display their journey on a map. Location needs to be very accurate, which means I'll have to get user's location pretty often (every 5 or 10 seconds). As you can predict, this will be a very data heavy app.

My question is on the backend/db side; what is the most efficient way of storing this data? Which database should I use? I did my research a bit, I watched couple of PostGIS and MongoDb tutorials and saw that is a common choice.

On mobile app startup, app displays user's previous journey and starts tracking new one. I need to be able to retrieve this data to our mobile app very quickly, so I'll probably need some sort of filtering by coordinates, eg. retrieve every data point from x1 to x2, y1 to y2.

My initial thought was to use PostGIS but I still need some guidance on how to design database and API to do this efficiently.

I'm using .NET for my backend btw.

Watched some PostGIS and Mongo tutorials, still a bit confused.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why not store the coords on the phone? This will eliminate the fetching. You could do one/two way sync once in a while

Answer (score 0):

A sample set of coordinates (in MongoDB) like this

```
{
   type: "MultiPoint",
   coordinates: [
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
      [-73.856077, 40.848447],
   ]
}
```

has a size of 323 Bytes. The max. size of a document is 16 MiByte, i.e you could store around 500k coordinates. Assuming you have a coordinate **every** 5 seconds you could store coordinates for app. 1 Month.

It really depends what you like to do. Quite often people think "more data" = "better data", a common misunderstanding of Big Data. You should carefully think about, whether this much data really improves your application or whether it just slows down your app.

In order to simplify geo-data you can use algorithm like [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), perhaps it makes sense to store the data at different levels of details used for different zoom-levels of your map. Of course, this adds redundancy but downloading the full set of data into the app takes time.

Comment: He probably needs to store timestamps as well

Comment: @siggemannen yes, most likely - above example would be the bare minimum. With a **fix** interval, e.g. every 10 seconds on coordinate, one could skip the timestamps but I don't think this could be a realistic design.

Comment: Thanks @WernfriedDomscheit! And yes, I will probably need timestamps as well (requirements still a little vague). Btw, forget about the 5 seconds thing, that was me trying to explain how MUCH data there'd be. I did try Mongo, it's pretty quick even when querying 2 full documents (cca 30mb) without any filters and just returning them (this obviously will not be the case). This is something that could bite me in the *** if not designed properly now, so I really appreciate all input.